# Multiple Equatable functions in one class

Tags: swift

I would like to know if its possible to have multiple Equatable functions in one class. My current problem is from this example:

```
class Ingredient: Equatable {

static func == (lhs: Ingredient, rhs: Ingredient) -> Bool {
    return lhs.ingredientId == rhs.ingredientId && lhs.price == rhs.price
}

//    static func == (lhs: Ingredient, rhs: Ingredient) -> Bool {
//        return lhs.ingredientId == rhs.ingredientId && lhs.price == rhs.price && lhs.quantity == rhs.quantity
//    }
}
```

As you can see I would like to have commented equality function but it doesn't work this way because I already have one. I need both functions working. Is there any optimal solution for this?

Comment: Optimal solution? The optional solution is to determine what uniquely identifies an object and use that when implementing `Equatable` and then use your own "specialised"  functions for any other type of comparison, perhaps create a protocol to define them if they are to be implemented for several classes

Comment: How would that make any sense? Which function do you want Swift to use to determine equality?  Either the quantity matters or it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can not.

From the math definition of the function:

> A function is a process or a relation that associates each element x of a set X, the domain of the function, to a **single** element y of another set Y (possibly the same set), the codomain of the function.

In general, by defining more than one function with the same name which takes **arguments of the same types** you create ambiguity which leads to unpredictable results. So this behaviour will generate compile time error.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have multiple definitions of the `==()` function (the function that gives you conformance to the equatable protocol) but you can write a complex implementation of your `==()` function that uses more complex logic to decide how to compare two objects. You could even add a class variable to your class and have your `==()` function use that variable in deciding how to compare values, although that seems like bad design.